# Flutter JSON Nested to Lisview Builder

Tags: mysql, json, listview, flutter

sorry i have searched on youtube and google but i'm still not getting any clue to parse JSON nested to listview builder.

my json result

```
[
    {
        "ID_Type": "1",
        "Type": "Food",
        "Item": [
            {
                "SLU_Number": "3",
                "SLU_Name": "Food"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID_Type": "2",
        "Type": "Beverages",
        "Item": [
            {
                "SLU_Number": "1",
                "SLU_Name": "Non Alcohol"
            },
            {
                "SLU_Number": "2",
                "SLU_Name": "Alchohol"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i want ID_Type, Type,Item (SLU_Number and SLU Name) throw all value to Listview.builder

thank you.

my code on flutter, i follow some code on youtube and that throw the value to List but i don't how to throw the value to Listview.builder

```
class Products {
  final ID_Type;
  final Name_Type;
  final Items;

  Products({
    this.ID_Type,
    this.Name_Type,
    this.Items,
  });

  factory Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Products(
      ID_Type: json["ID_Type"],
      Name_Type: json["Type"],
      Items: Item.fromJson(json["Item"]),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  final SLU_Number;
  final SLU_Name;

  Item({
    this.SLU_Number,
    this.SLU_Name,
  });

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Item(
      SLU_Number: json["SLU_Number"],
      SLU_Name: json["SLU_Name"],
    );
  }
}
```

here below is my Future to throw all the "json" result to List

```
    //------------------------------Start Syntax for List SLU
    final listslu = new List<ListSLU>();
    final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshlistslu =
        GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();


    Future<void> ListSLUs() async {
      listslu.clear();
      setState(() {
        loading = true;
      });

      try {
        final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.ListSLU);

        if (response.contentLength == 2) {
        } else {
          final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
          data.forEach((api) {
            final b = new ListSLU(
              api['ID_Type'].toString(),
              api['SLU_Number'].toString(),
              api['SLU_Name'].toString(),
            );

         listslu.add(b);
         print(api['SLU_Name'].toString());
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
      print("Error List SLU :");
      print(e);
  }
}

  //------------------------------End Syntax for List Type
```

after parsing all json result and then all value from json i throw to body

```
Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listslu.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,i){
              final z = listslu[i];
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){

                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Text(z.SLU_Number +' - '+ z.SLU_Name),
                    ],
                  ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          )
      ),
```

Comment: what have your tried, paste your code.

Comment: i have paste all my code above. please review my code.

Comment: There is a great tutorial for parsing nested json here https://medium.com/@slamet/nested-json-in-dart-1517cfd07822